# Revision history for deleted .gs file

Tags: google-apps-script

I've noticed that the "See revision history" within the editor is for each .gs file.  If I have a project where I've deleted a second .gs file, there's no way to see or restore any revision history of that deleted file, correct?  Even if it is still being used on a deployed version of a standalone app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that seems to be a limitation of the current revision history screen. I can see how it would be useful to have access to the revision history of a deleted file, to restore it, and you can file a feature request for this on the [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list).